# OpenMDAO: Replacing ExecComps with normal Components changes output

Tags: openmdao

I was running the code of 'Sellar exmaple' from the tutorials. According to the docs given on the [tutorial page](http://openmdao.readthedocs.org/en/1.5.0/usr-guide/tutorials/sellar.html), the `ExecComp` is just a shorthand for declaring a normal `Component`. So I tried redefining the `ExecComp`s in the example as normal `Component`s and use them in the same example.

The `ExecComp`s in the example are defined as follows -

```
self.add('obj_cmp', ExecComp('obj = x**2 + z[1] + y1 + exp(-y2)',
                             z=np.array([0.0, 0.0]), x=0.0, y1=0.0, y2=0.0),
                             promotes=['*'])
self.add('con_cmp1', ExecComp('con1 = 3.16 - y1'), promotes=['*'])
self.add('con_cmp2', ExecComp('con2 = y2 - 24.0'), promotes=['*'])
```

The normal `Component`s which I defined are as follows -

**Objective component**

```
class SellarObjective(Component):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarObjective, self).__init__()    
        self.add_param('x', val=0.0)
        self.add_param('y2', val=0.0)
        self.add_param('y1', val=0.0)
        self.add_param('z', val=np.zeros(2))    
        self.add_output('obj', val=0.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        unknowns['obj'] = params['x']**2 + params['z'][0] + params['y1'] + exp(-params['y2'])

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        J = {}
        J['obj', 'x'] = 2 * params['x']
        J['obj', 'y2'] = (-1) * exp(-params['y2'])
        J['obj', 'y1'] = 1.0
        J['obj', 'z[0]'] = 1.0
        return J
```

**Constraint 1**

```
class SellarConstraint1(Component):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarConstraint1, self).__init__()

        self.add_param('y1', val=0.0)
        self.add_output('con1', val=0.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        unknowns['con1'] = 3.16 - params['y1']

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        J = {}
        J['con1', 'y1'] = -1.0
        return J
```

**Constraint 2**

```
class SellarConstraint2(Component):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarConstraint2, self).__init__()
        self.add_param('y2', val=0.0)
        self.add_output('con2', val=0.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        unknowns['con2'] = params['y2'] - 24.0

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        J = {}
        J['con2', 'y2'] = 1.0
        return J
```

And I instantiate these newly declared `Component`s in the re-written implementation as -

```
self.add('obj_cmp', SellarObjective(), promotes=['*'])
self.add('con_cmp1', SellarConstraint1(), promotes=['*'])
self.add('con_cmp2', SellarConstraint2(), promotes=['*'])
```

Everything else in the code is same as that of the tutorial. But after executing both of them, when I compare the results - results don't match.

Am I missing something obvious here? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two minor issues with your replacement objective class:

1. the objective is a function of `z[1]`, no `z[0]`
2. the derivative of the objective with respect to z is an array, and you can't use `z[1]` as the key. You must use `z` instead.

Correct your objective comp to the following, and it should work:

```
class SellarObjective(Component):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SellarObjective, self).__init__()    
        self.add_param('x', val=0.0)
        self.add_param('y2', val=0.0)
        self.add_param('y1', val=0.0)
        self.add_param('z', val=np.zeros(2))    
        self.add_output('obj', val=0.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        unknowns['obj'] = params['x']**2 + params['z'][1] + params['y1'] + np.exp(-params['y2'])

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        J = {}
        J['obj', 'x'] = 2 * params['x']
        J['obj', 'y2'] = (-1) * np.exp(-params['y2'])
        J['obj', 'y1'] = 1.0
        J['obj', 'z'] = np.array([[0,1],])
        return J
```

Comment: `z[1]` instead of `z[0]` was a very trivial mistake on my part. Sorry about that.

Comment: the derivative mistake was a little trickier. When you declare derivatives of an array, treat each entry in the array as a separate variable.